# custom build with ol.control.defaults.extend

Tags: openlayers-3

I don't know how to define an export in my custom build. In my map definition I have:

```
controls: ol.control.defaults({ zoom: false, attribution: false })
  .extend([attribution])
```

But I can't seem to get the "exports" right in my build.json file. When I build I get errors like:

> No matching symbol found: ol.control.defaults.extend

In my build.json file I have:

```
"ol.Attribution",
"ol.control.Attribution",
"ol.control.defaults",
```

Followed by each of the following, one at a time:

```
"ol.control#extend",
"ol.control.extend",
"ol.control.defaults#extend",
"ol.control.defaults.extend",
```

(Obviously the trial-and-error approach) Any clue as to what I'm overlooking? Is "extend" a member of some other object?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`extend`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Collection.html#extend) is a `ol.Collection` method, so add this `"ol.Collection#extend"` to your build.json.